# Are name servers enough to point a domain to an S3 bucket host?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I recently bought three domains via some site, planning on pointing them to an S3 bucket.

The first one I succeeded in doing so, because I added both name servers, an A record, and a CNAME for the subdomain (www). Those I got from Amazon Route 53 (I added A record and CNAME myself).

The others I can't get to work, simply because the domain registrar site won't let me change anything but the name servers (don't ask me why).

My question: are or aren't the name servers enough to point a domain in the right direction? Is it impossible to host a site on an S3 bucket with my own domain with only access to name servers?

Comment: Once pointed at the AWS Route53 nameservers, the rest is done in AWS Route53. You'd add all DNS records (and you should use AWS's `ALIAS` type, not `CNAME` or `A` records) on the ROute53 end.

Comment: @ceejayoz So I don't need to touch anything but the name servers on the registrar's end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll need access to the actual DNS records to point the domains to the S3 bucket.

You can use Route53 for all of your domains. Just create Hosted Zones for each, then check your NS entry in your newly created zones, then go to your registrar and update your domains to use these NS servers - you can then use Route53 to manage all of your DNS records for all three domains.

Comment: But wait, your answer seems to contradict itself? It probably doesn't, but just to be clear: you mean I *don't* need access to the actual DNS configuration on my registrar (only name servers) because I can fix the rest in Route53? That was actually my question, even if didn't seem so.

Comment: You seem to be confusing your registrar with your DNS settings. The two are distinctly separate. Your registrar's nameservers control where your DNS records are held.

Comment: Maybe? My question is simply if I need to edit A records and CNAME records on the registrar's end, or if I *only* need to edit the name servers?  I suppose now that the answer is that I only need to edit the name servers, but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: To pass control of your DNS records to Route53, you need to change your name servers on your registrar.

Comment: A little annoying that you can't answer my question directly, instead typing around it, but okay, thanks. :)

Comment: @Yeats Some registrars may also provide managed DNS (i.e. the ability to change records other than the apex nameservers for the domain), but not all do. Other companies provide managed DNS solutions for domains that you have already acquired, but are not registrars and you cannot register domains through them. Does that help any?